# What happens to Javascript object created in function, once the function return?

Tags: javascript

My question is about js object created and stored in function. What do they becomes once the function returns? Here is a code example:

```
class userInfo {

  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  function greetings() {
    alert(`Hi, you're name is ${this.name} and you are ${this.age}`);
  }

  function renderUserInfos() {
    const userContent = document.createElement('ul');
    userContent.innerHTML = `
                         <li>${this.name}</li>
                         <li>${this.age}</li>
                         <button>Display User Info </button>
  `
    const displayButton = userContent.querySelector('button');
    displayButton.addEventListener('click',this.greetings.bind(this));
  }
}

function render(name, age) {
 const user = new userInfo(name, age);
 user.renderUserInfos();

 return;
}

render('John',25);
```

Now I expect the "displayButton" to trigger the "greetings" function, once I'll click on it.
However, as the "user" object that has been created in the "render" function will be garbage collected once this function will return, how can the "greetings" function be triggered??

Comment: `renderUserInfos` does not appear to actually append the `userContent` or the `displayButton` to the document, so it won't get rendered, and the click event listener should never get triggered

Answer (score 0):

In general you should not worry about garbage collection.

According to [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/garbage-collection-in-javascript-b1e4dbffb51) on medium there are 3 common mistakes you should keep in mind:

1. Excessive use of globals by creating global variables or by omitting
   the var keyword in local scope
2. Forgetting the clearing of timers like setInterval()
3. Unnecessary use of closures

**REMEMBER**

Closures always keep a reference of the variables from the parent function even if the parent function has completed execution.

So to answer your question:
The object 'userInfo' does **not** get garbage collected